# No Provider For Paypal Error is showing in my Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal, ionic3

I am working in my Ionic app and I have just installed the **PayPal plugin** for my Ionic App.

**Used These for adding the plugin.**

```
ionic cordova plugin add com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk
npm install @ionic-native/paypal
```

I have also import in my **checkout.ts**:

```
import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from '@ionic-native/paypal/ngx';

constructor(private payPal: PayPal) { }
```

But after adding this, it is showing the error: No Provider for PayPal.

Then I have added it to the **app.module.ts**:

```
import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from '@ionic-native/paypal';

providers: [PayPal]
```

But after adding the PayPal to the Provider, **it is showing the error:**

> Type 'PayPalOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type
>   'PayPalOriginal' is missing the following properties from type
>   'FactoryProvider': provide.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **checkout.ts** you are importing correctly,

> import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from
>   '@ionic-native/paypal/ngx';

But in the **app.module.ts** the import path is wrong

```
import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from '@ionic-native/paypal';
```

You have to import like the one you did in **checkout.ts** file. `ngx` is missing in app.module.ts file

Comment: Only this will work import { PayPal } from '@ionic-native/paypal/ngx'; like this in app.module.ts.

Comment: Or I have import this to work. import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from '@ionic-native/paypal/ngx';

Comment: use the import you did it for the checkout.ts file in the app.module.ts

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer. It has solved my query.

Comment: Once Again. Thank you for the answer.